# Is there a command to list all the servers currently being run locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, command-line, terminal, localhost

Im sure this question has been asked before I am just having a really hard time finding it... Currently when I go to start my rails server, I am running into

```
`initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 5000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

obviously port:5000 is currently being used but is there is quick way to list all local web servers and to also kill said servers. Please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ps aux | grep ruby
```

or

```
ps aux | grep rails
```

find the server
then

```
kill -9 pid
```

Comment: What if the server being run in the background is not a rails server?

Comment: You can use sudo lsof -i :5000, to look for app running on port 5000. Then kill -9 with the pid.

Comment: I could do this as well `ps aux | grep php`