# Svelte Serving Wrong Project

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server, svelte

I created a new svelte project, opened the new directory in visual studio code and when I run `npm run dev` in the terminal and open my web browser, the project I see isn't the one I just created its one I previously worked on.

So my initial reaction was to delete the previous project, as it wasn't important, then ran the command again and to my surprise the project that no longer exist is still being served at the address. I've restarted my system and so on.

**Does anyone know why this might be happening?**

Comment: Have you tried list all processes and searching for another server running? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35189508/112233 add more information about the output of the commands in that link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal - it got cached.
Assuming you're using Chrome:
Open the developer tools (F12, or three dots -> more tools -> developer tools), go to Application, Clear storage, and Clear site data. Then, reload the page.

If this doesn't work, press Ctrl+F5 (Cmd+Shift+R on macOS).

Comment: I tried doing as you said and it didn't seem to work but after a quick google search I found if you press ctrl+F5 it will clear the cache on refresh. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Maria Miller, this should be added to the answer. (cmd + shift + r for Mac).

Comment: No... I meant to say you should add what  OP wrote in his comment: "ctrl+F5 it will clear the cache on refresh" - this is how you do a **hard refresh** on Windows. and for Mac: `cmd+shift+r`, this is what helped the OP (and me too multiple times...), and that's why I think it should be added to your answer...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Done.